# Python module docstring

Tags: python, module, docstring

How do I print the docstring of my python module file, from my main file?  Let's say I have a python module file called Projectile.py, which defines a class inside it called Projectile.  Then I have another python file called main.py.  In main, I want to access the module level docstring.  How do I do this?
I know how to print the docstring for the class and the methods. 
For example, to print the class level docstring from my main file, it would just be:

```
print(Projectile.__doc__)

Output:  This is the class docstring:  Simulates the flight of simple projectiles near the earth's surface, ignoring wind resistance. Tracking is done in two dimensions, height (y) and distance (x).
```

But how to print the module level docstring??  Thanks!

```
     """This is the module docstring"""
        from graphics import *
        from math import *

        class Projectile:
            """This is the class docstring:  Simulates the flight of simple projectiles near the earth's surface, 
               ignoring wind resistance. Tracking is done in two dimensions, height (y) and distance (x)."""

            # Constructor - TO INITIALIZE INSTANCE VARIABLES
            """This is the constructor docstring"""
            def __init__(self, angle, velocity, height):
                self.initialVelocity = velocity
                self.xpos = 0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the docstring, using `__doc__` field:

```py
import x; print(x.__doc__)
```

Or use [help](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#help) function to get interactive help:

```py
import x; help(x)
```

Comment: This prints out all the info on my Projectile.py file, but doesn't print the docstring at the very top of the file/module.  In my example, from my main.py file, I'm trying to print out the docstring """This is the module docstring""".

Comment: Got it. I extended my answer.

Comment: when I do print(Projectile.__doc__), it prints my class docstring, but not the module docstring.  Is this because I'm naming my module the same as my class?

Comment: How do you import `Projectile` class? Don't use `from Projectile import Projectile`.

Comment: Duh! OMG that was it! Thank you!